# Funcionamiento de powershell y el uso de objetos

Tags: poo, powershell, línea-de-comandos

No logro entender como funciona powershell, en la documentación del mismo dice que powershell usa objetos en lugar de texto, lo que no entiendo como es que un comando es un objeto, no se si tenga que ver mi forma de ver la programación y aunque conozco la programación orientada a objetos no logro comprender como es que powershell maneja los "cmdlets" como objetos y como es que funcionan.
Un ejemplo es cuando alamacena el resultado de un comando es una variable, luego veo el tipo de variable que es y me lanza que es inputobject eso no lo entiendo.
Me gustaría que alguien pudiera responder esta duda de una manera sencilla, por que me cuesta mucho trabajo entender el powershell, Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Una de las formas en que Powershell es diseñada para manipular objetos es en la canalización.  La canalización en unix fué basada en caracteres the texto.  La canalización en powershell  está basada en objetos.

```
get-childitem . | format-list
```

Lo que pasa por la tubería en este ejemplo es archivo por archivo.  Cada archivo es un objeto.  Esto resulta en un system mucho más flexible, porque es innecesario decifrar lo que pasa por la tubería.